# WPF(MVVM) UserControll. Как вернуть свойство из UserControll в ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, usercontrol, paintevent, dependencyproperty

**Всем привет!**

**Цель** - хочу написать UserControll светлофор. Что б прибиндить из ViewModel к нему 3 свойства. И если я нажму на одну из лампочек (зеленый , красный , желтый) изменялись эти свойства.
Хай свойства называются FLAG1,FLAG2,FLAG3 типа bool. И при нажатии на лампочку , загорался свет и одно из свойств переходило в состояние true, а другие в false.

**Или же что б огни саме переключались.**

**Пример** - нажмимаю на центральну лампочку светлофора - цвет этой лампочки стал желтый и FLAG1 = false; FLAG2 = true; FLAG3 = false;

Comment: Я вам в предыдущем вопросе с часами показал, как сделать кликабельные переключатели, вот на их основе думаю без труда сделаете то, что надо. Делаете просто три `DependencyProperty`, привязываете такие кнопки к ним, ну и все, готово.

Comment: Но я так и пытался сделать , но почему то биндинг не работает , я не знаю. Тот пример что я делал , там ещо было изначально свойство из dependency property showsecond , и в MainViewModel , тоже было это свойство. И я биндел mode=twoway, но почему то не работал. Может чтото нужно в clock.xaml.cs тоже чтото кроме dependency property прописать? Типу создать new binding()? Но я не знаю как правильно.

Comment: Попытки свои показывайте, без кода обсуждать это смысла нету.

Comment: Я для подобных целей переопределял шаблон RadioButton(рисовал нужный мне контрол). Дальше в xaml:  <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding MyProperty}>". Где MyProperty является свойством bool во ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

**Вот код, сделайте лучше, так как он плохой. Если что время по простому методу обчисляю. Знаю что рендер будет задерживатся.**

[image: Фото каталога]

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;


using TrafficLight.ViewModel;
using TrafficLight.View;

namespace TrafficLight
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            new MainWindow() { DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel() }.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TrafficLight.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TrafficLight.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        xmlns:tr="clr-namespace:TrafficLight.UserControls">
    <Grid>
        <tr:Traffic Flag1="{Binding Flag1, Mode=TwoWay}" Flag2="{Binding Flag2, Mode=TwoWay}" Flag3="{Binding Flag3, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TrafficLight.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TrafficLight.ViewModel
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {

        }

        private bool flag1 = false;
        public bool Flag1
        {
            get 
            { 
                return flag1; 
            }
            set 
            { 
                flag1 = value;
                Print();
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(Flag1)); 
            }
        }



        private bool flag2 = false;
        public bool Flag2
        {
            get
            {
                return flag2;
            }
            set
            {
                flag2 = value;
                Print();
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(Flag2));
            }
        }



        private bool flag3 = true;
        public bool Flag3
        {
            get
            {
                return flag3;
            }
            set
            {
                flag3 = value;
                Print();
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(Flag3));
            }
        }



        private void Print()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----------------");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Flag1: " + Flag1);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Flag2: " + Flag2);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Flag3: " + Flag3);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----------------");
        }

    }
}
```

**Traffic.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TrafficLight.UserControls.Traffic"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TrafficLight.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>




        <Ellipse
             Width="200"
             Height="420"
             Fill="WhiteSmoke"
             Stroke="Silver"
             StrokeThickness=".5" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>



        <Ellipse
                 Width="100"
                 Height="100"
                 Fill="Gray"
                 Stroke="Silver"
                 StrokeThickness=".5"  x:Name="Green"/>
        
        <Ellipse Grid.Row="1"
                 Width="100"
                 Height="100"
                 Fill="Gray"
                 Stroke="Silver"
                 StrokeThickness=".5" x:Name="Yellow" />
        
        <Ellipse Grid.Row="2"
                 Width="100"
                 Height="100"
                 Fill="Gray"
                 Stroke="Silver"
                 StrokeThickness=".5" x:Name="Red" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Traffic.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace TrafficLight.UserControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для Traffic.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Traffic : UserControl
    {


        public bool Flag1
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(Flag1Property); }
            set { SetValue(Flag1Property, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty Flag1Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Flag1", typeof(bool), typeof(Traffic), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public bool Flag2
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(Flag2Property); }
            set { SetValue(Flag2Property, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty Flag2Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Flag2", typeof(bool), typeof(Traffic), new PropertyMetadata(false));


        public bool Flag3
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(Flag3Property); }
            set { SetValue(Flag3Property, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty Flag3Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Flag3", typeof(bool), typeof(Traffic), new PropertyMetadata(false));

       


        public Traffic()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            int number = 0;

            if (Flag1 == true)
            {
                number = 1;
            }
            else if (Flag2 == true)
            {
                number = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                number = 3;
            }
            StartLight(number);
        }


        private void StartLight(int number)
        {
            DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += Tick;
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }


        public async void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                if (Flag1 == true)
                {
                    Flag1 = false;
                    Flag2 = true;
                    Flag3 = false;
                }
                else if (Flag2 == true)
                {
                    Flag1 = false;
                    Flag2 = false;
                    Flag3 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Flag1 = true;
                    Flag2 = false;
                    Flag3 = false;
                }


                SetColors();
            }


            );

        }


        private void SetColors()
        {
            if(Flag1 == true)
            {
                Green.Fill = Brushes.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                Green.Fill = Brushes.Gray;
            }




            if (Flag2 == true)
            {
                Yellow.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
            }
            else
            {
                Yellow.Fill = Brushes.Gray;
            }




            if (Flag3 == true)
            {
                Red.Fill = Brushes.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                Red.Fill = Brushes.Gray;
            }
        }








    }
}
```

**Результат**

[image: Результат]

**ViewModelBase.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TrafficLight.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChange(string name = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

**RelayCommand.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace TrafficLight.ViewModel
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { 
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; 
            }
            remove { 
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; 
            }
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
        {
            if (CanExecute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this.canExecute == null ? true: canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.execute?.Invoke(parameter);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: Это ответ к моему вопросу)))).

Comment: Повторяете одни и теж ошибки. Повторю: Вы не должны хотеть из C# кода каким-либо образом взаимодействовать с контролом. Если у вас такое есть - все, значит вы сразу делаете не так. Я вам ведь под предыдущим дал решение для стрелок, вот его и применяйте. Берете `<RadioButton>`, делаете ему нужный вид, привязываете свойство `IsChecked` к DP (`<RadioButton IsChecked = "{Binding Flag1}">`), ну и также, в стиле, на основе этого же свойства делаете триггер `<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">(нужный цвет)</Trigger>`, все, вот ваш светофор, без единой строки C# кода.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ
Я понял , просто я только ваше решение увидел, щас буду его читать.
Да , только я решил попробывать сделать так , что б огни сами переключались через 1 секунду. Это к моему заданию не относится. Но вопрос а так можно в xaml сделать без c#? Если да , то как? Спасибо что наставляете на добрый путь.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можно все подытожить. 
Нужно стараться для контролов писать менее кода в c#. 
Но если пишеш в с# , то контрол не должен зависеть от viewmodel, а только от dependency properties.
Если идет стандартная прорисовка то юзать xaml.
Если своя фигура (наследуваемая от Shape)- то с#.

Comment: XAML не логика, а вид. Ваша сейчас задача - отделить вид от данных. Вот просто разбейте все на 2 слоя, где цвет, шрифт, анимация, положение, да и прочее - это часть визуальная (View), а логика - это отдельная, абстрактная часть, которая вообще не должна знать про какие-либо контролы, работая лишь с базовыми классами. Другими словами, вы должны сделать так, чтобы небыло `x:name` вообще в XAML, но он принимал все изменения, например, свойства `Flag1` и на их основе менял цвет (через привязку). Если прям по коду, то `SetColors()` должен быть в XAML, в C# лишь флаги и логика их переключения.

Comment: Также помните, контрол - это лишь отображение входных данных, не более. Вот с часами, посмотрите внимательней на код, где я задаю время, внутри контрола, или за его пределами? Правильно **за**. Сам контрол у меня лишь получает на вход `TimeSpan` со временем и конвертирует его в углы для стрелок, не более. Также и тут, почему у вас внутри контрола таймер для переключения цветов? Это представьте, если бы вы использовали `TextBox`, а вам в него сама система что-то писала, без вашего ведома. Ваш таймер с переключением цветов должен быть в VM слое, за пределами контрола, а контрол лишь отображать.

Comment: Ну и вот это `Flag1 = true; Flag2 = false;` - это ерунда, ведь за вас это должен делать сам XAML, внимательно смотрите стрелки, там пример с `RadioButton`, которым можно задать группу и они сами будут выключать остальные, при клике на другой. Если так сделаете, то ваш код будет своидться к простому `Flag1 = true;` затем `Flag2 = true;` (первый флаг автоматом станет `False`). Ну и также посмотрите как я у часов сделал таймер, там простой бесконечный цикл, без каких либо таймеров и тем более, без `Dispatcher`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я понял, спасибо что так много своего времени затратили на меня. Я знаю что это вульгарно прозвучит, но не могли б вы скинуть сылку на ваш проект с Clock, просто хочу с ваших рук посмотреть на него. Если откажетесь я пойму, так как вы все мне расписали.

Comment: Вам мало того, что было в ответе?)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я поняв все есть в ответе). И еще вопрос так как вы нереально опытны в этой сфере и я думаю вы поймете в чем дело. У меня есть  вопрос на stackoverflow https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1431440/c-wpf-skiasharp-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-pdf-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-window-xaml
И также продолжение к нему можно считать это https://github.com/Oaz/AvaloniaUI.PrintToPDF/issues/1
Я юзаю AvaloniaUI.PrintToPDF который строиться на SkiaSharp. И такой трабл случился.

Comment: Проект я вам наверно скидывать не буду, ибо считаю, что пока вы сами это не напишете, не познаете, вы не сможете понять материал и двигаться дальше. Я думаю, того ответа более чем достаточно, чтобы по пунктам пройтись и сделать это все самостоятельно. Я вот вам полностью написал часы, а вы вон спустя вопрос, делаете светофор с теми же ошибками. Согласитесь, это не есть хорошо. Касательно вопросов про PDF - я наверно дал бы ответ, если знал, да?) А касательно авалонии - я ее терпеть не могу, уж извиняйте.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  ок . Спасибо большое за такой вклав в мое развитие) . Очень благодарен вам. От просто начал учить wpf(mvvm) и здесь с начала все такое непонятное)